# Getting typed OR selected value from combo box

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I have a combo box (myCB) in a form.  The user can either select a drop down value or type a value in the box.  When the user clicks a button, I want to get the value in the combo box for use in a query.

I am using myCB.Column(0) to grab the value.  This works if the user has clicked a selection in the combo box.  However, if the user has typed the value, then myCB.Column(0) is null.  I have also tried myCB.Text and myCB.Value.  Both give null.

How can I grab the combo box value regardless of whether it was selected or typed?

Edited to add properties:
Row Source: "SELECT DISTINCT Item FROM tblItems" (this is set in VBA code, and not in property sheet)
Bound Column: 1
Column Count: 1
Column Widths:
Control Source: ItemName

Comment: Just referencing combobox without Column(0) works for me. Edit question to show combobox properties: RowSource, BoundColumn, ColumnCount, ColumnWidths. ControlSource.

Comment: The `Value` property should give the result you are looking for, and does in my brief testing.

Comment: @June7 - Edited as requested

Comment: @Lee Mac - The Value property gives the correct result if the value was selected from the drop down, but it gives Null if the value was typed into the combo box.

Comment: I tested with bound and unbound combobox. Don't see anything about those settings to cause this issue. Cannot replicate. I was assuming LimitToList property is set to No.

Comment: Yes, LimitToList is No.

Comment: @Chell I cannot replicate the results that you describe in my own testing - could you please post the code for the OnClick event handler for your button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  I was grabbing the combo box value after `DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNewRec` in the OnClick procedure, and the behavior was wonky.  Running the value-testing stuff before a new record is accessed yields the correct behavior.  Thank you everyone for your help.